# Problem in downloading apps from Google play

Tags: google-play-store

What does the message, "your account wasn't signed in for Google play store" mean?

Comment: Hi! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Did you thoroughly search/research for an answer before asking your question?  Tell us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far and why it didn't meet your needs? This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself and it saves us from reiterating obvious answers.

Comment: Did you check out [tag:google-play-store] tag wiki? It has information on diagnosing and solving common issues with Google play store.

Comment: I can't find any reference to the error message mentioned here. Is that the full & proper error message? If possible, please include the screenshot if the error message is long. Providing proper error message will significantly pinpoint the issue. Else, the nearest that I found is [Error: You haven't accessed the Google Play Store app on your device with this email account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6178908)

Answer (score 2):

The message means that you haven't signed in your google account, due to that you can't access your google play store, play store needs verified email to access the application.

- Do one thing, go to settings- > Accounts -> Add Account and add your Google account.
- Again go to your Play Store, choose your emailID if play store prompts you with any mailID, you must be able access it now..

Hope that helps